# How to change the children of tabbedpage xamarin ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

The problem just occurrs on Xamarin iOS.

I get the exception:
UITabBarController setSelectedViewController: only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            var page = ((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));

                            this.Children[2] = page;
                            this.CurrentPage = Children[2];
                            RedeAtendPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
                        });
```

The exception occurs at line this.Children[2] = page; Probably because i´m on the Children[2] page.

Just happens on Xamarin iOS. On Android works nicelly.

Comment: The problem is not that you are already on Children[2] page, but that your new instance `page` is not in your tab bar controller's list. I'm not sure how to fix it... Did you register `Page` for navigation?

Comment: @DennisSchröer So, the problem is my Children[2] is a Popup Menu (like a submenu). When user clicks, i change the Children[2], that is also CurrentPage, for the New Page (selected on the Popup). Can i register the 2 pages of the Popup, but let them invisible on TabbedPage ? Maybe if i set, by example, `Children[2] = Children[5] ; CurrentPage = Children[2]; ` This way, the page would be on my tab bar controller´s list, wright ?

Comment: Might work, but it's a really ugly hack (if it even works). Why are you trying to achieve this? To me, your question sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you just navigate within the tab?

Comment: @Dennis Because my client needs 6 tabs. But one of them has 2 options (sub menu) and I need to dont show the navigation bar when click on the submenu. Need to change the currentpage

Comment: If I understand you right, this is my suggested approach: Navigate to the submenu page and set navigation bar height to 0. This will effectively hide the bar. Set height back to it's `MeasuredHeight` when you navigate back from the submenu.